# Can you make addTextChangedListner wait?

Tags: android

Is there any way to make a addTextChangedListner wait for a specified amount of time before launching the next intent.
My problem is coming when it is reading from an input, it only reads the first character, then immediatly launches. If it could something like ".wait(100); this would be time to read all input.

Many Thanks

Input is coming from scanning device, and i would prefer not to use a button to say when to launch for speed.

```
final EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

String results = name.getText().toString(); 

Intent one= new Intent("com.test.testing");
one.putExtra("key", results);
startActivityForResult(one, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.

I guess that the TextChangedListener executes in a separate thread that the one its called from. So calling something like `Thread.sleep(100);` could do the job?

Comment: That's not right: It's performed on the UI thread. So sleeping is not a good thing, will just block the whole UI before it performs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a button like *Do it*? That technique doesn't seem very transparent to the user and might be very disturbing. I wouldn't recommend to do that...

Anyway, you could use a timestamp.

```
// somewhere in your class
private long lastAction = 0;
private static final long WAIT_UNTIL_ACTION = 100;

// your listener
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (lastAction == 0) {
            // initialize it
            lastAction = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAction > WAIT_UNTIL_ACTION) {
            lastAction = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // perform it here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a much simpler was instead, the input had an automatic carriage return on the end, so just used a onKeyListner to look out for it instead. Thanks for all the help!